# DD-WRT - Redirecting internet traffic based on source Subnet

Tags: networking, iptables, dd-wrt

Following question has a long description. I hope some one in similar position finds it helpful. Please be patient. My problem is at the end.

First of all, I have the following setup in home:

```
--MODEM (ADSL) - ISP INTERNET : 192.168.0.1
  |
  -- WIRELESS ROUTER (DDWRT) : 192.168.1.1
```

I have a L2TP VPN service that I need to use must of the time to access internet. As DD-WRT dont support L2TP as a VPN Client, I ended up setting it up as the primary WAN connection. Works as expected and my traffic goes through the VPN connection from all Wireless clients and Ethernet ports. Exactly what I want.

[image]

Now in some rare cases I dont want to use the VPN connection. Such as when it goes down. Until now I had to go to router control panel and set the WAN settings to "DHCP" to get direct internet access. Then again when VPN become online, revert the settings back.

I found that difficult (specially cuz no one else knows how to do that) and so I decided to create a Virtual Wireless interface that use the Modem IP address as the gateway and as result any device connected to it gets the direct link to internet. So I created a Virtual Wireless Interface and added it to a new bridge, then configured DHCP to assign any client connected to it an IP in 192.168.3.x IP space. Following screenshots helps you understand the setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Until now everything works as expected. Now I had to find a way to send the traffic from this subnet (192.168.3.x) to 192.168.0.1 which is the ADSL modem and as result bypass the PPP connection of router.

Using my limited knowledge of IP tables and some help from internet I wrote the following script:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.3.0/24 table 200
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2 table 200
ip route flush cache
```

IP Table contains the following rules before the execution of above commands:

```
root@router:~# ip route
default via 192.168.100.198 dev ppp0  scope link
50.105.xxx.xxx via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.255.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev vlan2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.100
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1 via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2
192.168.3.0/24 dev br1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.1
192.168.100.198 dev ppp0  scope link
```

After execution in table 200:

```
root@router:~# ip route list table 200
default via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2
```

As you can see, above commands works well but I have two problems:

1. I cant find a reliable way to execute it at every restart
2. VPN connection wont connect again after a disconnected. In fact after a disconnect any client except the ones with 192.168.3.x IP address loose their internet access.

Take a look at the IP table rules after a disconnected:

```
root@router:~# ip route list table 200
default via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2
root@router:~# ip route
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.255.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev vlan2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.100
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1 via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2
192.168.3.0/24 dev br1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.1
```

based on the above result I guess it is because of not having a default rule, But why and how can I solve it? It is important to know that without executing my custom commands, everything would works normally.

What I tried already:

1. Startup Script:

I used the below command to create a script to get executed at wan gets connected. didnt had any success.

```
mkdir -p '/tmp/etc/config/'
echo "ip rule add from 192.168.3.0/24 table 200
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2 table 200
ip route flush cache" > '/tmp/etc/config/direct.wanup'
chmod +x '/tmp/etc/config/direct.wanup'
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following rules to the **Firewall** script solved my problem completely:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2
ip route delete 8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2
ip rule add from 192.168.3.0/24 table 200
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev vlan2 table 200
ip route flush cache
```

[image: Firewall]